# shade block between two lines, values vary with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting the relationships between speed and time for four different species (each in a different facet).  For each species, I have a range of speeds I'm interested in, and would like to shade the area between the min and max values.  However, these ranges are different for the 4th species compared to the first three.

```
#data to plot as points
species <- sample(letters[1:4], 40, replace = TRUE)
time <- runif(40, min = 1, max = 100)
speed <- runif(40, min = 1, max = 20)
df <- data.frame(species, time, speed)

#ranges of key speeds
sp <- letters[1:4]
minspeed <- c(5, 5, 5, 8)
maxspeed <- c(10, 10, 10, 13)
df.range <- data.frame(sp, minspeed, maxspeed)

ggplot() +
  geom_hline(data = df.range, aes(yintercept = minspeed), 
             colour = "red") +
  geom_hline(data = df.range, aes(yintercept = maxspeed), 
             colour = "red") +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(time, speed),
             shape = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(~species) +
  theme_bw()
```

How do I:

1. get `geom_hline` to only plot the max and min ranges for the correct species, and
2. shade the area between the two lines?

For the later part, I've tried adding `geom_ribbon` to my plot, but I keep getting an error message that I'm unsure how to address.

```
geom_ribbon(data = df, 
              aes(ymin = minspeed, ymax = maxspeed, 
                  x = c(0.0001, 100)), 
              fill = "grey",
              alpha = 0.5) +
```

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (40): x, ymin, ymax

Comment: Rename `sp` to `species` in df.range, since that's what you are using for `facet_wrap`. For the `geom_ribbon` line, try replacing that with something like `geom_rect(data = df.range, aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = minspeed, ymax = maxspeed), fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5)` instead?

Comment: Thanks @Z.Lin. using geom_rect does provide a nice shaded area on each figure, but unfortunately, it doesn't just add 1 shaded area/species, but rather there are four rectangles for each plot.  Do you know how to get facet_wrap to recognize this?  I did change sp to species.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, the following *should* work. Perhaps there are other unobserved differences between your actual use case & the example in your question?

```
colnames(df.range)[which(colnames(df.range) == "sp")] <- "species"

ggplot() +
  geom_hline(data = df.range, aes(yintercept = minspeed), 
             colour = "red") +
  geom_hline(data = df.range, aes(yintercept = maxspeed), 
             colour = "red") +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(time, speed),
             shape = 1) + 
  geom_rect(data = df.range, 
            aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = minspeed, ymax = maxspeed), 
            fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~species) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

Data used:

```
df <- data.frame(species = sample(letters[1:4], 40, replace = TRUE),
                 time = runif(40, min = 1, max = 100),
                 speed = runif(40, min = 1, max = 20))

df.range <- data.frame(sp = letters[1:4],
                       minspeed = c(5, 5, 5, 8),
                       maxspeed = c(10, 10, 10, 13))
```

Comment: Thanks @Z.lin.  It looks like it was an issue with my original data.